# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown JCDI-enabled managed bean com.sun.faces.taglib.html in JAX-RS webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jsf, glassfish

I have a project that uses JSF 2.2, runs on Glassfish 4.1 and I recently created REST webservice inside it using Jersey (JAX-RS).

My webservice is annotated as @javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped, injects a few @EJB's and has one @POST endpoint which @Produces and @Consumes JSON's.
However the webservice runs fine, I still get tons of exceptions like that ones when I log in to web interface of the app:

```
Warning:   Exception during invocation of PreDestroy-annotated method on JSP tag handler [com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.GraphicImageTag@48c2b3fb]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown JCDI-enabled managed bean com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.GraphicImageTag@48c2b3fb of class class com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.GraphicImageTag
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.managedbean.ManagedBeanManagerImpl.destroyManagedBean(ManagedBeanManagerImpl.java:652)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.destroyManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.destroyManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:437)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.jsp.ResourceInjectorImpl.preDestroy(ResourceInjectorImpl.java:119)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool.release(TagHandlerPool.java:213)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.common.helpButton_tag._jspDestroy(helpButton_tag.java:73)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.common.helpButton_tag.doTag(helpButton_tag.java:123)
    at org.apache.jsp.help_005fbar_jsp._jspx_meth_myTag_helpButton_0(help_005fbar_jsp.java:643)
    at org.apache.jsp.help_005fbar_jsp._jspx_meth_f_view_0(help_005fbar_jsp.java:277)
    at org.apache.jsp.help_005fbar_jsp._jspService(help_005fbar_jsp.java:151)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
```

However, the web app runs fine.

When I remove the @RequestScoped annotation from my webservice class, the EJB's are not injected into it, and I don't get the exceptions from web app.

I see that the problem comes from the custom JSP tag, but I don't know where to start looking, because as I said before, when I remove the annotation, the exceptions disappear.

The target situation is to get rid of the exceptions when running webservice.